# How can I highlight one row in antd table with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So I have a table with coordinates, and when I click on one particular row it should be highlighted and other rows should be default color.
For now it looks like  this:

```
const TableComponent = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(active);
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
      rowClassName={active ? "green" : null}
      onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
        return {
          onClick: (event) => {
            setActive(true);
          }, // click row
        };
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default TableComponent;
```

When I click on one row all of the rows get highlighted, how could I make it only to one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the active record, and compare it with the `record` argument of the `rowClassName` prop function. If they are the same, then set your custom class name to this row you clicked.

`rowClassName` prop has `function(record, index): string` signature, you should always return a string instead of `null`.

```
type ID = string | number;

const TableComponent = () => {
  const [activeRecord, setActiveRecord] = useState<{ id: ID }>();

  console.log(activeRecord);

  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
      rowClassName={(record) =>  record.id === activeRecord?.id ? "green" : ''}
      onRow={(record) => {
        return {
          onClick: () => {
            setActiveRecord(record);
          }, 
        };
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default TableComponent;
```

`antd` version: v5.0.5

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState()
  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      rowClassName={(record, index) => (index === activeIndex ? 'green' : null)}
      onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
        return {
          onClick: (event) => {
            setActiveIndex(rowIndex)
          }, // click row
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}
```